# loop through nav menu when li menu's hovered

Tags: javascript, dom

I am not familar with JavaScript DOM , mostly i use jQuery for script.. I am trying on JavaScript and in trouble with the below code.
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

What i would like to do is when LI is hovered, the nested OL is displayed..somehow, the below code doesn't work, even it doesn't show any error in console.

Please help me...

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.gnb');
var li = ul.children;
var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', myFunction(myshow));
  li[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', myFunction(myhide));
}

function myshow() {
  ol.style.display = 'block'
}

function myhide() {
  ol.style.display = 'none'
}

function myFunction(fn) {
  return function(e) {
    if (e.target.type !== "mouseenter") return;
    fn.call(e.target)
  };
}
```

```css
.gnb {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.gnb>li {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
}

.sub.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gnb">
  <li class="gnbLi">
    <a href="#">Why Mailchimp?</a>
  </li>
  <li class="gnbLi" onmouseenter="myFunction()">
    <a href="#">What You Can Do</a>
    <ol class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually you just need the css :hover to show your nested elements. you can see this simple example. https://jsfiddle.net/7pn2jato/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
Basically what you have done is dealing with an array as a single element because of `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of `ol` in the whole page.

---

Solve: 
1. you need to get the nested `ol` inside the `li` that's being hovered using 
  -`event.target` to get the clicked li. 
  - `querySelector` to get the `ol` under that `li`.
2. you need the `ol` to be displayed/removed depending on the event.

---

so only change the Javascript to be as the following and it will work

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.gnb');
var li = ul.children;

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
  li[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',mouseleave );
}

function mouseenter(event) {
 var ol = event.target.querySelector('ol');
  if(ol){
    ol.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function mouseleave(event) {
 var ol = event.target.querySelector('ol');
  if(ol){
    ol.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct and clean, I changed a little bit of your code:

```js
    (function () {
        var ul = document.querySelector('.gnb');
        var li = ul.children        
        var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            li[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', myFunction(myshow));
            li[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', myFunction(myhide));
        }

        function myshow() {
            ol.style.display = 'block'
        }

        function myhide() {
            ol.style.display = 'none'
        }

        function myFunction(fn) {
            return fn;
        }
    })();
```

```css
        .gnb {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
        }

            .gnb > li {
                float: left;
                width: 150px;
                height: 100%;
                list-style: none;
            }

        .sub {
            display: none;
        }

            .sub.show {
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
    <ul class="gnb">
        <li class="gnbLi">
            <a href="#">Why Mailchimp?</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gnbLi">
            <a href="#">What You Can Do</a>
            <ol class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
```